# How to log an Error without leaking any security info or stacktrace?

Tags: java, security, exception, error-logging

When I run Fortify Scan on my project i do see that i'm logging the exceptions using

```
LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(),e);
```

and it says this is not the right way because attckers may get access to this info and get system info from this and plan an attack.

What is the best way to do this?(without compramising on the security)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That reasoning is frankly ridiculous in most cases.  Your LOGGER object should be writing to the local filesystem, and if a remote attacker can access your filesystem you've got *way* bigger problems.

Restrict access to your log files as appropriate, and then log to your heart's content.

Comment: I tend to agree with you, in general, for a well designed and maintained system. But you would be surprised by how many systems I've seen that you can enter "mysite.com\logforj.log" and BAM, see the log file.

Comment: If you are logging to within your webroot, you should fire your developers ;-)

Comment: But more seriously, that's like saying "if we host our source code on our site, people can download our source code!!!"  The fix?  Don't put your source code or log files up on your site!

Answer (score 3):

You could switch logging off in production, but this would make you great disadvantage when the final user would report error and you would have no idea what had happened.

You should treat your logs as critical data and protect access to them on operating system level, such as access to database files. If attacker would access the database, he would compromise the system anyway. At best only the system admin should have access to log files, and should give them to developers only when needed (critical error on production etc.).